# How to make list of partial functions in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

i need to write code like this in clojure.

```
-- haskell
fns = map (,) [1..3]
head fns $ 1
-- => (1,1)
fns <*> [1..3]
-- => [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
```

doesn't work

```
(def fns (map (partial list) (range 1 3)))
((first fns) 1)
;; => ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

works, but i think this isn't idiomatic way

```
(def fns (map (fn [x] `(partial list ~x)) (range 1 3)))
((eval (first fns)) 1)
;; => (1 1)
```

Comment: Did you look at what the `ClassCastException` is telling you?

Comment: Yes. So, I wrote the last code. But, I think that code is ugly. How can I make this better?

Comment: OK, but rather than punting and using eval, is there any way to make the cast succeed?  What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14559071

Comment: How can I take a function from list without evaluating. And is there any way to use that function without eval?

Answer (score 6):

The function `(partial list)` is equivalent to just the function `list`. It's not like haskell where everything is curried - I think you intended `partial` to see that it's been given only one argument, `list`, and curry itself up to wait for a second argument. But really that should be `(partial partial list)`: you are attempting to partially apply the function `partial` itself.

Note also that partially-applied functions are not as common in clojure as they are in haskell, partly because they just don't read so well. Instead of `(map (partial partial list) (range 1 3))`, if I wanted to build a list of functions like this, I would probably write `(for [i (range 1 3)] (fn [j] (list i j)))`.